# How to add space between value and unit in Conky

Tags: conky

My Conky currently displays following with `${mem}` and `${memmax}` variables:

```
Mem: 3.63GiB / 15.2GiB
```

I want it to look like:

```
Mem: 3.63 GiB / 15.2 GiB
```

Is this possible with some configuration?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2794/punctuation-with-units

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a bit heavy going, but if your conky was compiled with `lua` then you can write a small piece of code to split the output string and add a space. Create a file, say `~/myformat.lua` with contents:

```
function conky_myformat(arg)
 local val = conky_parse(arg)
 return string.gsub(val, "([%d.-]+)(%a+)", "%1 %2", 1)
end
```

and add to your `.configrc` in the `conky.config` part:

```
lua_load = '~/myformat.lua',
```

and replace each function like `${mem}` by a call to the above function, for example

```
conky.text = [[
 old: ${mem} and ${memmax}
 new: ${lua myformat ${mem}} and ${lua myformat ${memmax}}
]]
```

lua does not use regular expressions (regex), but patterns which are similar, see
the [documentation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/). 
`%d` matches a digit, `%a` a letter, and `()` is used to capture the match for use in the replacement string as `%1` and so on.

Alternatively, you could compile your own conky from source, changing the function `human_readable()` in [src/conky.cc](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/blob/master/src/conky.cc#L572).

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.11.6 added a space between values and units, in about August 2020. I'm not sure if this was an intentional change, it was part of a fix for SI units.  It should be in 20.10, but not 20.04.

The latest source includes a configuration setting for what to use as a spacer between values and units, including nothing, but this is not yet released so you'd need to build it yourself.

Comment: It would really improve your answer if you could add a reference to the changelog or something!